# .val() Only Returns 1st row in PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP form which is used for updating records which have come from an array, I'm currently testing a button to show the current Name in the record that appears but my issue is that the 1st row record always comes through even when I click on a different row in my array.

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="update_form">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<label>Name</label>  
<input type="text" name="fnameupdate" id="fnameupdate" class="form-control fnameupdate" value="<?php echo $row['Firstname'] ?>" /> 
</div>
</div>
</form>
<button name="updaterecord" id="updaterecord" class="btn btn-success omhformupdate floatleft"><i class="material-icons floatleft">add_circle</i><div>Update Appointment</div></button>
```

When the button is clicked this is the event thats being fired:

```
    <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.omhformupdate').click(function(){  

       var nameupdate = $('#fnameupdate').val();  
              window.alert(nameupdate);

        });  
    });  
</script>
```

The alert does fire however only the first row is coming back all the time even though another row has been selected, What is causing this?

Comment: HTML element IDs can only be used once per page. Change `$('#fnameupdate')` into `$('.fnameupdate')`

Comment: The code you provided only produces one row.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am inclined to think that the HTML snippet is the output for a single `foreach(){}` loop for a database result.

Comment: `.val()` only returns the value of the first element that matches the selector. If you have a selector that matches multiple elements, you need to use `.map()` or `.each()` to loop over them.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Each input element has it's own form element?

Comment: @Barmar how can I add .each() or .map() into my statement?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am only observing and guessing at the problem. It's OP's design, not mine...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, IDs must be unique, and an ID selector will just select the first element on the page with that ID. You should use a class selector.

Second, if you want the value of the input right before the button, you need to use a DOM traversal methods to find it, not just any element with the class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.omhformupdate').click(function() {

    var nameupdate = $(this).prev().find('.fnameupdate').val();
    window.alert(nameupdate);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="update_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fnameupdate" id="fnameupdate" class="form-control fnameupdate" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button name="updaterecord" id="updaterecord" class="btn btn-success omhformupdate floatleft"><i class="material-icons floatleft">add_circle</i><div>Update Appointment</div></button>
```

Comment: I've changed the jquery script and the result is coming back as undefined? the class is defiantly set in the HTML so im not sure why this is appearing

Comment: I don't know. Is the HTML for every record the same as what you showed in the question? Is the `<form>` right before each update button?

Comment: I’m using a separate php page for the actual form itself so the same html is being used all the time.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant. When it gets to the client, does the HTML look like what you posted?

Comment: yeah the HTML is an exact match with what’s being posted?

Comment: Then I don't know what's wrong. It clearly works here.

Comment: does opening a div inside of a modal have any effect on getting the values?

Comment: My code uses navigation relative to `this`, so it shouldn't matter where it's opened. As long as the `<form>` and `<button>` are sequential, it should work.

Comment: What I have is a php page which comes back with all of the rows in a table and when I click on an update button a modal appears with all the row information. When the button is clicked its opening another PHP page which I have included in my index, would this be an issue showing the value as whatever I try it still comes back as 'undefined' when alerting the current value in a row. @Barmar

Comment: It should only come back as `undefined` if `$(this).prev().find('.fnameupdate')` can't find the input element. If the HTML in the modal is like in my answer, it should work. So I suspect it's not really the same, maybe there's a div around the button, or it's inside the `<form>` instead of after it?